# QuickBooks Online API Authentication Failed

Tags: quickbooks

I got the access token using Oauth 2 in Quickbooks Intuit developer apis.

The scope is *`com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting`*

I was able to get access token and refresh token using Quickbooks authentication and authorization endpoint.

Then I tried to get companyInfo with calling this api.

https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/companyId/companyinfo

When calling this api or others, I am always getting this error.

```
Message: message=AuthorizationFailed; errorCode=003100; statusCode=403, Detail: The access token does not have sufficient scope
```

I am sure access token is right. but I am not certain why I got this error.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: were you able to find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and then I came to know that my quickbook client was initializing with empty client_id and client_secret. it worked after i changed those to right values.